# Datepicker options not working on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-rails

The gems i'm using are twitter-bootstrap-rails and jquery-rails.

Basically what I'm, trying to do is set the minDate on the date picker however none of the options are being accepted.

$(selector).datepicker minDate: 0

Weirdly enough when I do a .on on the datepicker 'changeDate' works.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I just figured out that jquery-ui isn't being loaded with the page. I guess this means I am using the bootstrap datepicker, which I thought needed the jqueryui library, however no matter what I did I couldn't get the site to load jqueryui?

Comment: Can you paste your code and check if there are any errors in web console?

Comment: The code works when I have no options for datepicker. that's why i guessed that there was a problem with the options

Comment: Are you using this datepicker http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ ? It doesn't have minDate option...

Comment: the only gems i'm using are the ones mentioned above. actually that might be the problem. i am not the original author of the code but i'm assuming the datepicker comes from the jquery-rails gem, which should have minDate. i tried added the gem you mentioned and used startDate to do the same thing to no avail

Comment: Are you sure you are not using jQueryUI? jQuery itself doesn't have datepicker control. Can you try this http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max ?

Comment: i know that but i checked the application.js file and there was a reference to jquery-ui so yes i think its jqueryUI datepicker. however minDate doesn't work either way.

Comment: Like this?
$(selector).datepicker({
    minDate: 0
});

Comment: Exactly but in coffeescript

Comment: Do you get any errors in web console?

Comment: I just checked it on CoffeeConsole and no it doesn't give any error syntactically

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the downloaded version of bootstra-datepicker wasn't the latest version. I got the latest version on [GitHub](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker). Gotta be careful next time!